# Не могу понять почему выбивает ошибку firebaselist

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Ребята,помогите.
Пытаюсь вывести список бесед,но выбивает ошибку.

```
public class Lobby extends ListFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button btn;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapterList;
    private String str;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    public Lobby() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lobby, container, false);

        user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lobby_list);
        readLobby();
        return v;
    }

    public void readLobby() {
        names=new ArrayList<String>();
        adapterList = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(getActivity(), String.class, R.layout.lobby_list_item, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby")) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View vg, String model, int position) {
                TextView textView=(TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.lobby_list_items);
                textView.setText(model);
                names.add(model);
            }
        };

        list.setAdapter(adapterList);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                TextView textV=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lobby_list_items);
                String str=textV.getText().toString();
                for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++){
                    if(str.equals(names.get(i))){
                        Fragment yfc = new Chat();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("tag", names.get(i));
                        yfc.setArguments(bundle);
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,yfc).commit();
                        /*finish();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name",names.get(i));
                        startActivity(intent);*/
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addNewLobby(String name) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("lobby").child(name)
                .setValue(name);
    }
}
```

Вот ошибки:

```
by.ittech.test_chat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: by.ittech.test_chat, PID: 30551
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:346)
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:147)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста,где мой косяк?)

fragment_lobby.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="by.ittech.test_chat.Lobby">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lobby_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/lobby_add"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/lobby_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/lobby_add"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

lobby_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lobby_list_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ребята,всё заработало.
Помогло просто заменить наследование ListFragment на Fragment

Answer (score 2):

Вы в делаете list.setAdapter(adapterList) еще до того, как оно проинициализировано в onCreateView();

Comment: теперь уже другая ошибка:
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'